# Как передать данные в шаблон Джданго?

Tags: python, django

Как я могу вызвать в шаблоне значение из скрипта?

```
vacs = [{'name': 'WEB-Разработчик/программист (SEO-правки)', 'description': 'Hastra Agency ищет разработчика с опытом работы с связи с ростом отдела SEO-продвижения. Требуемый о...', 'key_skills': ['HTML', 'CSS', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'SE']}, {.....}, {....}]
O']
```

Как я сделал ниже - не работает

```
 {% for item in vacs %}

    <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">

        <h2 class="mb-4">Последние вакансии профессии Web-разработчика</h2>
        <p>{{ item[0]['key_skills'] }}</p>


{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `item.0.key_skills`

Comment: Так не работает

Comment: А, у вас список `vacs` и `item` это словарь из него? Ну тогда просто `item.key_skills` и не надо никаких индексов

Comment: vacs = {'name': 'WEB-Разработчик/программист (SEO-правки)', 'description': 'Hastra Agency ищет разработчика с опытом работы с связи с ростом отдела SEO-продвижения. Требуемый о...', 'key_skills': ['HTML', 'CSS', 'MySQL', 'PHP', 'SEO
'], 'employer': 'Hastra Agency', 'salary': 'None - 60000 RUR', 'area': 'Москва', 'published_at': '2022-12-12', 'alternate_url': 'https://hh.ru/vacancy/73732873'}

Comment: item - переменная тип которой в цикле пробегаюсь по vacs

Comment: Автор, а зачем вы отметили лучшим ответ, который не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такой вариант, из вашего представления передаёте переменные и указываете html файл

views.py

```
def update_html(request):
    var = len(parser.array_len_element)
    var_categoryes = len(parser.pagination_iteration_arr)
    
    return render(request, 'local.html', {'len': f'{var}', 'categoryes': f'{var_categoryes}'})
```

local.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<p>Категорий загружено:</p>
<p id="datacategoryes">{{categoryes}}</p>
<p>Товаров загружено:</p>
{% for item in len %}

    <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">

        <h2 class="mb-4">Последние вакансии профессии Web-разработчика</h2>
        <p>{{ item[0]['key_skills'] }}</p>


{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

далее соответственно можете уже его итерировать, в связке с js (к примеру для динамического обновления)всё то же самое, только js по триггеру ходит в ваш view и возращает json,html, и тд

Comment: Вы просто скопировали нерабочий код шаблона из вопроса

Comment: аргументируйте, почему он не работает?

Comment: Потому что в шаблонизаторе Django не существует синтаксиса с квадратными скобками

Comment: вам стоит почитать про навигацию по массиву и словарю в пайтон, как к стати и в других языках программирования таких к примеру как JS

Comment: Шаблонизатор Django - это не пайтон и тем более не JS. Повторяю ещё раз, в шаблонизаторе Django не работают квадратные скобки для навигации по массиву или словарю.